# rails, creates an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

Good Morning,

I have two scaffolds person and city.

```
rails g scaffold person :name, city_id
rails g scaffold city :cityname
```

and one formular view/people/

```
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :name %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :city_id %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :city_id %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cityname%><br />
    <%= f.text_field :cityname%>
  </div>
```

it doesnt go, i have to create an object of city and put the id in the city_id hidden_field and after that after create-button selected all should be saved in the database.

Not too hard or? Who would you make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to pass `city_id`.

```
  <%= form_tag url_for(:controller => :your_controller, :action => :some_action, :method => :get do %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :name %><br />
      <%= text_field_tag :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :cityname%><br />
      <%= text_field_tag :cityname%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

In controller:

```
  def some_action
    city = City.find_or_create_by_cityname(params[:cityname])
    person = Person.new(params[:name])
    person.city_id = city.id
    person.save!
  end
```

Comment: thanks, nice trick. I get this undefined method `cityname' for #<Person:0x38ad3b0>
Extracted source (around line #66):

63: 
64:   <div class="field">
65:     <%= f.label :cityname%>
66:     <%= f.text_field :cityname%>
67:   </div>
68: 
69:

Comment: @ddd bcz you are using `form_for`.. You can't use single `form_for` for two models which don't have association. So use `form_tag`.

Comment: i appended on every one _tag. For this one appears an error: <%= date_select_tag :eintritt %> What do you think about that?

Comment: and rails added an column to person which only includes the city.id